# Is there any component like angular-ui-tree for angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, angular6

I'm a new developper and i'm looking for a component like :

http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example

but for angular 6, with exactly the same functionnality (draggable, nested, build with a json like that etc...).

I find some component but either there are without draggable or without nested....

I used this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-component but it's working with mobx and the json file is not adaptable without change the whole code.

I have an json response from an api and i need to just display it and notify a change then reload the tree.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Best regards

Comment: check this https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable

Comment: Hello, first of all, thx for your answer, but i need something like http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example with a collapse/extend option and more important is the nested functionnality.

Answer (score 0):

I used the component that you mentioned and you can take a json response from an api and build the tree.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-component
```

You can check my source code

```
https://github.com/daniel-luna-gonzalez/controlGestionFront/blob/master/src/app/new-subject/addressee-tree.component.ts
```

The above code builds some like this:

[image: tree]